# Find public subnets of an existing VPC in pulumi

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, pulumi

How can I find the public subnets of an existing aws VPC with pulumi?

I have tried several approaches and one that seems to get close is below, but I can't seem to filter on an attribute of the subnet due to how the `pulumi.OutputInstance` works.
If `Subnet.mapPublicIpOnLaunch` was a `boolean` instead of a `pulumi.OutputInstance<boolean | undefined>`, it could be filtered like this:

```
const publicSubnets = aws.ec2.getSubnetIds({vpcId: vpcId})
  .then(s=> s.ids
    .filter(i=>aws.ec2.Subnet.get(`subnet-`+i,i).mapPublicIpOnLaunch))
```

Since `Subnet.mapPublicIpOnLaunch` is a `pulumi.OutputInstance` it can't be filtered on them without first resolving the output. I have trying wrapping everything in a call to `pulumi.output` in a few ways but still can't get the `Subnet.mapPublicIpOnLaunch` unwrapped so that it can be filtered on.

My current workaround is below, but this feels like a hack and I would like to do this in a more pulumi style way and not have to exec.

```
const execAsync = util.promisify(exec)
const publicSubnets = execAsync(`aws ec2 describe-subnets --filter Name=vpc-id,Values=${vpcId} ` + 
      "--query Subnets[?MapPublicIpOnLaunch].SubnetId")
      .then(r => JSON.parse(r.stdout) as string[])
```